# Why no squiggly lines in VS Code for bad javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code 1.4. I have added references to backbone.js (etc..) in main html file called backbone.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Hello World in Backbone.js</title>

  <!-- ========= -->
  <!-- Libraries -->
  <!-- ========= -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.0/backbone.localStorage-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
  <script src="app.js"></script>
```

I then type some incorrect code in the app.js file.

```
MyModel = Backbone.Mdd;
```

[image]

I was expecting VS Code to highlight this as incorrect. Is there something I need to do to enable this?

Comment: How exactly is it "incorrect"?

Comment: There don't appear to be any compile time errors in that code

Comment: I see. So it can't pick up that the object "Backbone" does not have a property named "Mdd"?

Comment: The attributes are resolved in runtime. You cannot tell statically if an object has a property in JS.

Comment: Technically your code isn't a syntax error. `MyModel` will simply have a value of `undefined`

Comment: If I reference `backbone.js` in the html file, should I not be getting intellisense in the app.js file, e.g. if I type `Backbone.` get a list of members e.g. `Model`. This is not happening...

Comment: Check out this article in the docs it describes how you can get Intellisense in your JS project: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_intellisense